# EEG Data Analysis

Tags: fft, python, eeg

I have recorded EEG data using openBCI which is in the range of -15000 to 15000 micro volts. I want to reduce this to the range of -100 to 100 micro volts. How do I do it?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to achieve. Besides clipping, you could ["filter by amplitude"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/75819/50076).

Comment: Divide by 150. What else are you asking to do?